# |-> meaning in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

What does `|->` mean in **systemverilog**?

For example:

```
$fell(clkreq_hold) |-> ##1 $past(clkreq)
```

What's the difference between `|->` and `->` ?

Answer (score 4):

`->` is a logical implication operator (See 11.4.7 Logical operators) `A->B` is equivalent to the Boolean expression `!A || B`.

`|->` is a property operator for overlapping implication. (See section 16.12.7 in the SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2017 LRM) `sA |->pB` in the clock cycle when sequence `sA` succeeds, begin an attempt to see if property `pB` succeeds. When sA and pB are both simple Boolean expressions, they appear as if they have the same functionality. Except, when sA is false, the implication is considered a vacuous success. (excluded from the successful passing's count)